# Add new text box on click of a button in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

How do I add new text box when submit button is pushed. This is what I have tried and I know there's some thing wrong. I am still new to angular js.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example - example-ngController-production</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('controllerAsExample', []).controller('SettingsController1', function ($scope) {

                $scope.contacts=[]
                $scope.addContact = function()
                {
                  $scope.contact.push({$scope.contact})
                }
            });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="controllerAsExample">
        <div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="SettingsController1">

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="contact" />
                </li>
                <li><button ng-submit="addContact()">add</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code, you are doing:-

```
        $scope.addContact = function()
        {
          $scope.contact.push({$scope.contact})
        }
```

This is where the problem is. If you just need to add an empty textbox, you just need to add an empty contact to contacts, and ng-repeat will take care of adding the new textbox in the list. Another thing is that you were pushing into contact, and not contacts.

Also, ngSubmit is used inside a form, which you do not have. So, use ng-click instead. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AtvpwrKYYu3rAKZoSSxY?p=preview) showing the code working.

```
            $scope.addContact = function()
            {
              $scope.contacts.push({ name: '' });
            }
```

Comment: What is track by index$ which you have added to the code?

Comment: if you don't do track by $index, you will get the error - Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed, because duplicate keys are not allowed in ngRepeat. By saying track by $index, it is giving each item a unique key, $index. For more information, see here - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=contact%20in%20contacts&p1=string:&p2=

Comment: @AbhishekJain does it really persist a value..?

Comment: @CodeSpark, my original solution won't persist the value. To make it persist, you will have to add the contact as an object, and not a primitive type. I have edited my answer and the plunker demonstrating this.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your `ng-submit` with `ng-click` that will solve your problem
And with that you need to change your object structure to persist a value, like you need to add contact number in contact object like `contact.number`

**Markup**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <input type="text" ng-model="contact.number" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="button" ng-click="addContact()">add</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('controllerAsExample', [])
.controller('SettingsController1', function($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = []
  $scope.addContact = function() {
    $scope.contacts.push({
    })
  }
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zBr4VbXzsWzq5SDSluDs?p=preview)

Comment: Please answer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829370/dynamic-dropdown-not-working-on-submit-in-angular-js

Comment: @CodeSpark check I've added answer there..the approach which I suggested here has helped their..Anyways look at mine answer there

Comment: it works.can you add a delete button to each element.