# Dynamic dropdown not working on submit in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Adding a combobox or deleting a combobox on clicking submit isn't working. I am calling a function in scope when submit is clicked.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Text Box</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('controllerAsExample', []).controller('SettingsController1', function ($scope)
        {
            $scope.comboBox = []
            $scope.addDropDown = function ()
            {
                $scope.comboBox.push('');
            }
            $scope.deleteDropDown = function (index)
            {
                $scope.comboBox.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="controllerAsExample">
    <div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="SettingsController1">
        <input type="text" ng-repeat="dropDown in comboBox track by $index" />
        <select ng-model="newValue" ng-options="n in n[]"></select>
        <input type="submit" ng-submit="addDropDown()" value="Add" />
        <input type="submit" ng-submit="deleteDropDown()" value="Delete" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This line `<select ng-model="newValue" ng-options="n in n[]"></select>` throws an error. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Add an empty combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change from `ng-submit` to `ng-click`.

Comment: Its adding text box rather than combo box when I use ng-click

Comment: @CodeSpark that's quite expected, given that your repeated element is `<input type="text" ng-repeat="dropDown in comboBox track by $index" />`: you're displaying as many inputs as they are elements in $scope.comboBox.

Comment: `<input type="text" ng-repeat="dropDown in comboBox track by $index" />` should be change to a select if you want a drop down list.

Comment: I changed it to `<select ng-repeat="dropDown in comboBox track by $index" />` and its working but the combo boxes are added right next to each other. I want it to add in next line

Comment: @CodeSpark you won't learn HTML by asking questions here. Take an HTML 101 tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to change `ng-submit` to `ng-click`, then you need to change your object `comboBox` the value of each combo will be inside the combo box element, that will provide you the proper binding inside `ng-repeat` like `dropDown.value` by doing this you will never gonna use `track by $index` because the newly created in created as object with new index.

**Markup**

```
  <div id="ctrl-as-exmpl" ng-controller="SettingsController1">

    <input type="text" ng-repeat="dropDown in comboBox track by $index" ng-model="dropDown.value" />
    <select ng-model="newValue">
      <option ng-repeat="n in comboBox track by $index">{{n.value}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="addDropDown()" value="Add" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="deleteDropDown()" value="Delete" />
  </div>
```

As I said here you need to switch to my approach which I suggest [**here in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30829313/2435473).

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/M660ClfLO4OwHL8UcnIS?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, but comoboxes are added horizontally. I tried giving `<br/>` tag but its not working

Comment: @CodeSpark make style of your input to `style="dislay:block"` should work look at here http://plnkr.co/edit/6fyeczChDOS6KDPZBSrh?p=preview plunkr

Comment: Its working but the add button should be on left and drop down should on the right