# how to add ng-model to dynamically created input text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mongodb

This is my angularjs code to create input text fields dynamically.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
    //statically added textfields
    value1:<input type="text" placeholder="Give inspection details. Eg. 10:00." ng-model="store.static1" required />
    value2:<input type="text" placeholder="Give inspection details. Eg. 10:00." ng-model="store.static2" required />

    //dynamically adding textfields
    enter the number of new fields to be created:<input type="number" id="in_num"  />
    <button type="button" id="submit"> Create text fields </button>
    <div id="dynamicInput" ></div></td>

    //button to add values to the database
    <button type="submit" ng-click="addValues($event)> add to database </button>
</form>
```

"ng-click="addValues($event)"" helps add these values to a mongodb database which i have already done.

javascript code used to make these fields is:

```
 $(document).ready(function(e){
$('#submit').click(function(){     
 var inputIndex = $('#in_num').val();
    for( var i=0; i<inputIndex; i++)
    {
      $('#dynamicInput').append('<input type=text  id=id_'+ i +' style=width:100%; padding:12px 15px  ng-model=store.value'+i+'/>');
    }
});
});
```

On clicking the "add to database" button the values only from first and second textfields are geting added to the database but not the values added from the dynamically created textfields. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You're mixing jquery and angular in a way that doesn't work very well. There's no clean workaround for that.

Comment: **Suggestion:** Instead of generating elements with jQuery, you can create an array of object and loop though `ng-repeat`! `model` will get set there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your dynamically added input fields do not have a click event when you add them with jQuery. Adding `ng-click` is not enough. You would have to use `$compile` to let angular parse this element.

However, the much smarter way is to not use jQuery at all and let the fields be generated by angular itself with `ng-repeat`.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('dynamicFieldsController', dynamicFieldsController);

dynamicFieldsController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function dynamicFieldsController($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.numOfFields = 0;
  vm.fields = [];
  vm.add = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.numOfFields; i++) {
        var index = vm.fields.length;
        vm.fields.push(index);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='dynamicFieldsController as vm'>
  <input placeholder='num of fields' ng-model='vm.numOfFields'>
  <button ng-click='vm.add()'>add</button>
  <input type='text' ng-repeat='field in vm.fields' value='{{ field }}'>
</div>
```

In this example you can add any number of elements and bind `ng-click` events to them. They will work out of the box, since parsed with angular. Your `addValues` function now simply has to use `vm.fields` to actually add the values to database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go through [Add new text box on click of a button in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828545/add-new-text-box-on-click-of-a-button-in-angular-js)

http://www.shanidkv.com/blog/angularjs-adding-form-fields-dynamically