# Angular and jQuery: Events not attached to dynamically created HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I am using jQuery to dynamically create new elements in an Angular Form. The form is built using Template Driven Forms approach. The dynamic elements are successfully created but they are not assigned events/callbacks apparently because the component was already compiled and did not re-compile for the dynamic elements.  This keeps the new elements from reporting data or responding despite that the name  attribute and ngModel directive is assigned to it. How do I go about this? I have to read the form data for storing in database.

The TypeScript File code which generates the new component's HTML is as under (do not focus on class/ID names etc for I modified them for simplifying question statement). The function uses a counter for assigning unique name to the new input element.

```
private counter = 0;

increaseElementDynamically(){
this.counter++;
var htmlTagDef = '<input #benchReff'+this.counter.toString()+' ="ngModel" type="text" class=" form-control mb-3" id="bench'+this.counter.toString()+'" required name="bench'+this.counter.toString()+'" ngModel>';
$("#myDiv").append(htmlTagDef);
console.log(htmlTagDef);
```

}

The input element is written as under in the component's HTML file

```
 <div class="form-group col-lg-3 border-right border-primary">
            <label for="benchGroup">Bench Members</label>
            <div ngModelGroup="benchGroup">
                <div id="customDiv">
                    <input #benchReff ="ngModel" type="text" class=" form-control mb-3" id="bench" required name="bench" ngModel> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary float-right m-3" (click)="iincreaseElementDynammically()">Add</button> 
 </div>
```

Even if a simple click event is assigned, it wont work for the dynamically created elements since they were created on runtime.

How can the proper dynamic behavior be achieved with functionality?

Comment: your function is called "increaseElementDynamically" but in the HTML you call "iincreaseElementDynamically" (two i's at the start) Could that be your problem?

Comment: No, the issue was jQuery was creating elements, but Angular was never becoming aware of their presence. Issue got solved by eliminating jQuery from doing the job and handing it to Angular itself using arrays and ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

you need to attach click event or any other event handler using parent element delegation.

```
$('#myDiv').on('click','#bench', function(){ // will be triggered on click of bench input which is added dynamically
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: How to use this for the data reporting? The elements are supposed to report data due to the ngModel assigned to them.

Comment: I have provided solution to attach click event handler for dynamically created elements. for Angular ngmodal, you should visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861926/how-to-add-ng-model-to-dynamically-created-input-text-fields

Comment: ng-Repeat won't work but ngFor eventually solved the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: jQuery was operating on front end whereas the component was recompiling. Better approach was to eliminate jQuery and use ngFor directive. For new [dynamic] elements, new IDs can be pushed to an array with ngFor operating on same array to dynamically create elements which fully supported Angular functionality.